# A sliding piston-cylinder system contains a constant mass of gas inside

Tags: thermodynamics

I am confused about how a sliding piston-cylinder system would operate given that it contains a constant mass of gas.

I think that a system like this would have a non-constant volume since the height of the piston disk would be able to increase/decrease. I also think this system would be able to deliver and receive work since volume is not constant. However, I don't think it would be able to transfer heat to its surroundings.

Comment: Is there any reason you think you are wrong on those first two points? 
But then why don't you think it will get hot when work is done (it will)?

Comment: check wikipedia?

Comment: Your personal theory about it not being able to transfer heat to its surroundings is interesting.  So, if you put the piston-cylinder system into a bucket of ice water, the gas would not cool down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right in thinking that the gas will have a constant mass (unless it is somehow allowed to escape). Its volume can vary: since it is a gas, it can be compressed so that its volume (and with its volume, its density) will decrease. In the same way, it can be allowed to expand. In this case, since the gas will tend to fill the whole available volume, its volume will increase, and since its mass must be constant, its density will decrease.

With the compression/expansion, there is going to be work involved, as you say. If the volume is varied by a small amount $dV$ at pressure $p$, the work done by the gas is:
$$dW = -p dV$$
Note that $dV$ can be positive (if the gas is expanding) or negative (if the gas is compressing). Since pressure is always positive, the work is going to have opposite sign to the change in volume. This is because we want to say that $dW>0$ means that the internal energy of the gas increases. (we could also say the opposite: it's just a convention) So if $dV>0$ and the gas expands, it means that it is pushing the piston, so the gas is doing work and its internal energy decreases: thus $dW<0$. Similary for the case $dW<0$.

You're not right however in believing that it won't be able to transfer heat with its surroundings. There is no reason why it shouldn't: like it was mentioned in the comments, if the walls of the container allow heat transfer and you place the hot container in a bucket of ice, it will cool. Whether the system is allowed to exchange heat with its surroundings depends on the individual problem, and cannot be determined a priori. In fact, we call a thermodynamic system:

- *open*, if it can exchange both matter and energy with its surroundings
- *closed*, if it can exchange energy, but not matter
- *isolated*, if it cannot exchange neither energy nor matter

Which one it is depends on the setup. A typical system which involves no heat transfer is an adiabatic system: one where, say, the compression of the piston is very fast and thus there is no time for the system to exchange energy as heat. So in this case the change in internal energy will come from work only.